# 60 second delay between microservices in bluemix

Tags: spring, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, websphere-liberty

I have a problem. I have a few apps on Bluemix using cloud foundry apps, where one of them calls the others. The problem is that when I call an isolated microservice, a delay doesn't exist. When I call to an edge (proxy) microservice, a delay of 60 seconds exists.

The Edge microservice doesn't contain code other than a redirect petition to another microservice. All microservices are in the same space and account.

I use a Cloud Foundry app on IBM Bluemix with Liberty for Java and the Spring Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to add a comment so having put this in as an answer!

This sounds like an internal network routing question on IBM Bluemix rather than anything with the application, Liberty buildpack or Spring. I'd suggest raising a support question directly with IBM to help debug this

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/support/index.html#getting-customer-support